# Python get list of objects from list by value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I trying to get a list of objects from another list by object property value.

But when i'm trying if by the following code:

```
generalizing = [item for item in request_data if item.poll == '1']
```

I'm receiving error:

```
 'dict' object has no attribute 'poll'.
```

I'm completely new in python what am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your code.  probably if item[poll] == '1'

Comment: you have `request_data` and an item in it doesn't have attribute `poll`. So when interpreter tries to access `item.poll` it gets the error.

Comment: What @joelgoldstick said but with poll in quotes, i.e. `if item['poll'] == '1'`, unless `poll` is the name of a variable that you've defined earlier. If you're coming from JavaScript, `item['poll']` and `item.poll` are not the same thing.

Comment: @AlexHall yeah item['poll'] == '1' solved the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`item` seems to be a dict. So you have to retrieve its attribute using `item['poll']` instead of `item.poll`.